# Programmatically load data into solr using solrj and java

Tags: java, xml, solr, solrj

How can I load data from an xml file into solr using the solrj API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Java 6, you can use [Xpath](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html) to fetch what you need from your xml file. Then, you populate a [SolrInputDocument](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/common/SolrInputDocument.html) from what you extracted from the xml. When that document contains everything you need, you submit it to Solr using the **add** method of [SolrServer](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrServer.html).

Answer (score 6):

Thanks Pascal. I miss worded my question, I'm actually using groovy. But in any event your approach does work, but this was my solution:

```
CommonsHttpSolrServer server = SolrServerSingleton.getInstance().getServer(); 
def dataDir = System.getProperty("user.dir"); 
File xmlFile = new File(dataDir+"/book.xml"); 
def xml = xmlFile.getText(); 
DirectXmlRequest xmlreq = new DirectXmlRequest( "/update", xml); 
server.request(xmlreq);
server.commit();
```

The first arg to DirectXmlRequest is a url path, it must be "/update" and that the variable xml is a string containing the XML. For example

```
<add>
   <doc>
     <field name="title">blah</field>
   </doc>
</add>
```

Comment: Do you know if this can also be used for json and javabin?

Answer (score -1):

```
SolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient("http://localhost:8983/solr/jiva/");
String dataDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");    
File xmlFile = new File(dataDir + "/Alovera-Juice.xml");
if (xmlFile.exists()) {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(xmlFile);
    String str = IOUtils.toString(is);
    DirectXmlRequest dxr = new DirectXmlRequest("/update", str);
    client.request(dxr);
    client.commit();
}
```